# How to perform a task in android application in between when user has made a call?

Tags: android

Is it possible to hook or interrupt the process of the phone being dialed? Execute our code when the user has finished dialing the number, but not pressed “green”/go/send? And then optionally return control to the phone to complete the call?

Answer (score 0):

Android does support handling/intercepting out going call via  capturing `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` intent as [shown here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html).

> but not pressed “green”/go/send?

No. This is all happening *inside* Dialer application so far. Unless you wrote the dialer app yourself, you can't modify its internal workings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of **SecretCode** which can be use.